# Setting Unit in POSTGIS

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I'm new to [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) so my question might sound silly.
Currently working with [Points](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geometries.html#points) to represent geographical locations (with latitude and longitude only) and was wondering how I can use `[ST_DWithin][3]` with **meters** as a unit.

I can't find the right way and been lost in documentation trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that your points are `geography` rather than `geometry`, as explained in the [manual.](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

So you want a query like:

```
SELECT s.gid, s.school_name
    FROM schools s
        LEFT JOIN hospitals h ON ST_DWithin(s.geom::geography, h.geom::geography, 3000)
    WHERE h.gid IS NULL;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the points aren't typed as geography in their storage form but rather read as such, right ? The conversion can't be done beforehand (having the point stored as Geography and so not having to make the conversion) ?

Comment: The easier solution would be to store them as geography type but if you haven't then the conversion is not expensive (as you have used WGS84)